# httprequest and Authentication with ADFS from Universal App

Tags: c#, adfs, office365api, office365-apps

I am trying to make a httprequest to a web that is authenticated with ADFS of a private company. 
I am able to login and get the token of my App. I am sure I am doing it correct due to I can get the contacts of my O365.After getting the token I try to make a request to the web. As I already have the token, I try to include it in the header of the request. The answer that I receive from the web is always the html with the login web not the result that I am requesting. As additional information I have added a "Connected Service" O365 API from VisualStudio.

This is my code:

```
 public static async Task<string> GetAnswer(string wwweb)
    {

        var token = await GetAccessToken();


        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var url = wwweb;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ProxyAuthorization= new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            //  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

I have tried with the 3 lines ( 2 commented and one not) without success, always giving back company's login web. Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks